# libAVFAudio.dylib error for arm64 in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I have import AVFoundation framework in my project tried by removing and re-adding but not working.

I am getting following error:

```
ld: file not found: /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

> ld: in
>   '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation',
>   missing required architecture arm64 in file
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
>   (2 slices) for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

How to fix this error?

Comment: Fixed by removing the syetem framework from directory ex.Avifoundation,Xc.test

Comment: where located these files "ex.Avifoundation,Xc.test"

Comment: Check in project finder,in Build phases(Link Binaries) ,or check other version of Xcode.also check all libraries are imported correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed this by removing added twice the framework.

Comment: @Coder_A_D. alright.